# Why isn't there a notification center in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: desktop-environments, notification

Notification center is very convenient, making the OS more usable. I think it is a must-have component in daily use of any OS.

Android, IOS, macos, Windows all have their notification centers, so why doesn't it exist in Ubuntu/Linux?

**EDIT:** Sorry for the imprecision of this question. By "notification center" I mean an integrated panel for displaying informations **with support for push notifications**, like new messages, weather informations, reminders, app status, etc. Just like this in macos

[image: notication center in macOS]

You can swipe down from the top of the screen to show all kinds of information.

Comment: A couple of points: 1. This is not the right place to ask why some particular feature is missing. We're a community of users, not official developers/designers. 2. I don't know what you exactly mean by "*notification center*", but there is already something like this (at least in GNOME): https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/files/2013/01/notification-settings-details.png

Comment: If you find it lacking in your DEsktop (gnome if on 17.10, unity if on 14.04 or 16.04) then switch to a DEsktop that has it. The Budgie DEsktop lists that as a feature; so its available for Ubuntu, you just have to use it (or use Ubuntu-Budgie and have it by default).  To me it's just a 'so what I'll never use it ' but with Ubuntu Linux we have choice and can select the DEsktop we use according to our own use.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is an open source operating system.  It's designed to be free an open source and usability is secondary.  I'm sure there are notification programs for Linux and just because they are not installed by default doesn't mean that they don't exist.  The beauty of an open source operating system is that you can basically do anything on them so if you wanted to, you could code your own notification system and run it on your system.  I'd recommend trying different desktop environments to see what works best for you.

I found this which seems to do what you want it to do more or less: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/06/recent-notifications-ubuntu-16-04/

I'm sure if you look enough you'll find that someone else has already made a program to do what you want.

Above all else, remember that when using a free and open source operating system, there are no hard limitations.  You can change any and every component on the system to do whatever you want so if something doesn't fit your needs, change it.